# Oracle APEX LOV colum filter based on another LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to filter a column that is LOV, and is based on another LOV example:

I have a column LOV that is countries; and I can select any country.
And I have another column that is Regions; and I can select any Region based on the country that I selected.

This is just an example, the real job is with Entity, and Client.
I can select just one Entity, and that entity has many clients based on the column Entity.

I can filter in the user interface by the column countries.
But when I want to filter by Regions that option is not available

Somebody could help me! please.

["Empresa" is the LOV column "Father"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ0I6.png)

["Cliente" is the LOV column "child" or is based on Column LOV "Empresa"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPvdi.png)

Note: I don't know write english full, excuse me if is bad written.
You need I give you. thank you !

I don't know What could I do.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot which illustrates what you are saying? What is "user interface filter"? I can't imagine why you can filter by countries, but not by regions. From my point of view, yes - a screenshot might help.

Comment: Yes, I edited my question and there are 2 screnshoots, where "entity" is like countries, and "client" is like "regions". I can filter by entities/countries - But i can't do it by Clients/Regions

Comment: Its not possible to filter on a column that is cascading.

Answer (score 1):

Aha. You want to use built-in filters in Interactive Grid. I don't think that Apex offers cascading LoVs in that case (at least, not *declaratively*; maybe with some JavaScript, but I don't know it and can't assist).

Though, if you created your own **page items** - one for countries and another one for regions, then you could set **cascading** LoV property for the 2nd LoV - you'd just set parent item and Apex would do the rest of it for you.

For example: countries LoV:

```
select name d, country_id r
from countries
order by name
```

Regions LoV:

```
select name d, region_id r
from regions
where country_id = :P1_COUNTRY_ID
order by name

--> set P1_COUNTRY_ID to be its "parent" item
```

Interactive grid's query:

```
select *
from your_table
where (country_id = :P1_COUNTRY_ID or :P1_COUNTRY_ID is null)
   or (region_id  = :P1_REGION_ID  or :P1_REGION_ID  is null)
```